# Input with clear icon - loss of focus issue

Tags: javascript, input, blur

I have a clearable input like this:

```
+-----------------+
|               x |
+-----------------+
```

The clear icon is a span with a font glyph in the `:before`:

```
<wrapper>
   <input>
   <icon span>
</wrapper>
```

Validation of inputs is done on [blur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp) (which re-renders the input View for validation message and icon changes - this keeps the architecture simple). The issue I am experiencing is that by clicking the icon the input triggers a `blur` and then the icon `click`.

Can you think of a way to either:

a) Avoid triggering a blur -- I can only think of ditching font glyph and using a background image, but I am already using other glyphs for required, invalid etc in that position so it is undesired

b) Detecting that the blur was caused by the icon and not something else

Thanks.

Edit: Here is one idea, a bit lame using a setTimeout though: http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/td5VR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using mousedown and mouseup events to set/remove a flag. 
http://jsfiddle.net/td5VR/4/

```
var wasClicked = false;

$('input').blur(function(){
        $(".results").text(wasClicked ? "was clicked": "wasn't clicked");  
});

$('.something').mousedown(function(){
    wasClicked = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
    wasClicked = false;
});
```

Though you still need to disable keyboard navigation to the link by setting tabindex="-1".

Comment: awesome thanks! I didn't realise that `mousedown` would happen before `blur` and the `click` but it makes sense. Great!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few ideas of what might be happening and some approaches to try:

This is a guess, but perhaps what you're experiencing is something called **event bubbling**. Take a look at [this page](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) to learn more about it. You can prevent event bubbling in your click handler like this:

```
IconElement.onclick = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event // cross-browser event

    if (event.stopPropagation) {
        // W3C standard variant
        event.stopPropagation()
    } else {
        // IE variant
        event.cancelBubble = true
    }
}
```

(If you're using jQuery, you don't need to worry about the "IE variant")

You could also try adding `return false;` or `event.preventDefault()` and see if that works.

And one more approach is to check `event.target` in your blur handler:

```
InputElement.onblur = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event // cross-browser event
    var IconElement = [do something to get the element];
    if (event.target == IconElement) {
        // Ignore this blur event, or maybe even call "this.focus()"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. Unfortunately `e.target` is the input itself on the blur event, and the blur happens before the click. I also thought of these at first!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final very simple solution inspired by @Yury's answer:

```
$('.clearable-icon').mousedown(function() {
    // This happens before blur, so return false and stop propagation.
    return false;
});
```